# Asp net Project // Export Excel Function Fails

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel

Hello I am at the end of my apprenticeship and I have to create a project on my own. I am developing some kind of website and I wanted to add a function to download the sql information in a excel file. On my local Visual Studio version it works perfectly but as soon as I try to run in on my webserver with IIS it crashes with an error that is not helpful atleast for me with my limited knowledge. Hope someone from here can help to solve the problem.

```
Export Code:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

if (download_decision == "Partial")
            {
                //New Excel Application
                Excel.Application XL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                //Hiding Alerts and the File
                XL.Visible = false;
                XL.DisplayAlerts = false;

                //Workbook opened
                Excel.Workbook WB = XL.Workbooks.Add();

                //All Sheets are selected
                Excel.Sheets sheets = WB.Worksheets;

                //First Worksheets selected and renamed
                Excel.Worksheet WS = sheets.get_Item(1);
                WS.Name = public_language;

                //Name columns
                (WS.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range).Value = public_language;
                (WS.Cells[1, 2] as Excel.Range).Value = "English";

                (WS.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range).Font.Bold = true;
                (WS.Cells[1, 2] as Excel.Range).Font.Bold = true;

                (WS.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                (WS.Cells[1, 2] as Excel.Range).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                //SQL Reader
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    //SQL Server
                    conn.ConnectionString = sqlserver;

                    //Conncection establish
                    conn.Open();

                    //Get SQL Information
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from" + " " + selected_table, conn);
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    int counter = 3;

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string Source = (string)rdr["source"];
                        string Target = (string)rdr["target"];

                        //Values are written in file
                        (WS.Cells[counter, 1] as Excel.Range).Value = Source;
                        (WS.Cells[counter, 2] as Excel.Range).Value = Target;

                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                //Autofit Cells
                Excel.Range workSheet_range = WS.get_Range("A:B");
                workSheet_range.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

                //Save and Close
                WB.SaveAs(path);
                WB.Close();

            }
```

The error shows me this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x800ac472): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472]
   System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData) +1398
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Font.set_Bold(Object ) +0
   Glossary.Dashboard.Download_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\project1\project1\Dashboard.aspx.cs:107
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11773973
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5062

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're using Interop, which means the computer running the code must have MS Excel installed, and usually servers don't. Does your IIS server have MS Excel installed? Otherwise you'll have to change your whole code to use another library to read Excel.

Comment: Hello, yes I installed Excel on the server but to be sure I uninstalled it and I will try and reinstall it tommorow. If the error persists I will try to solve it but I tried the whole day and it is annoying. Thank you :)

Comment: If possible, I would suggest you to drop the Interop to use another library that isn't deppeding on Excel or COM, like EPPlus. If this is all your code, you shouldn't have much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Magnetron Thank you very much! Your idea was perfect. I am using EPPlus now. I altered my code and as a reward it worked and the speed increased dramatically.

My new code, with the working solution:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Collections.Generic;

if (download_decision == "Partial")
            {
                //New Excel Application
                ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
                var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(public_language);

                //Name columns
                using (ExcelRange Rng = ws.Cells[1, 1])
                {
                    Rng.Value = public_language;
                    Rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    Rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                }

                //Name columns
                using (ExcelRange Rng = ws.Cells[1, 2])
                {
                    Rng.Value = "English";
                    Rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    Rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                }

                //SQL Reader
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    //SQL Server
                    conn.ConnectionString = sqlserver;

                    //Conncection establish
                    conn.Open();

                    //Get SQL Information
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from" + " " + selected_table, conn);
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    int counter = 3;

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string Source = (string)rdr["source"];
                        string Target = (string)rdr["target"];

                        //Values are written in file
                        ws.Cells[counter, 1].Value = Source;
                        ws.Cells[counter, 2].Value = Target;

                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                //Autofit
                ws.Column(1).AutoFit();
                ws.Column(2).AutoFit();

                //Save and Close
                Stream stream = File.Create(path);
                excel.SaveAs(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }

//transfer to client
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/excel");
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                response.AddHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());
                response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                response.Flush();
                response.Close();
            }

            //file deleting
            File.Delete(path);
```